# jquery animation for li-elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate li-elements by clicking on the ul-element.(similar to BS collapse)
Initially all li-elements are hidden.

My markup is:

```
<ul title="mounting" id="0" class="39 mountin" data-color="anthrazit">
Mounting
<li id="0" class="261">
    <div class="label"><strong>grey</strong>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="1" class="262">
    <div class="label"><strong>black</strong>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="2" class="263">
    <div class="label"><strong>white</strong>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>

<ul title="earpad" id="3" class="39 earpad" data-color="red">
Earpad
<li id="4" class="261">
    <div class="label"><strong>grey</strong>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="5" class="262">
    <div class="label"><strong>black</strong>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="6" class="263">
    <div class="label"><strong>white</strong>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

My jquery code is:

```
$('#navi ul:not(.open)').click(function(){
    $('#navi ul li').hide();
    $('#navi ul').removeClass('open');
    $(this).find('li').slideDown();
    $(this).addClass('open');
});
```

Clicking on the ul opens the li with a slideDown animation.
The problem that I am facing is:
When I click on one of the li elements that are visible now, it starts the animation from the beginning. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: could you please share the CSS too?

Comment: It's not good practice to have multiple elements with the same `id`, id's should be unique

Comment: @Mamulasa Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here You can find some example

https://cssanimation.rocks/list-items/

Please check. I hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Do you need such behavior:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navi ul:not(.open)').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).prop("tagName") == "UL") {
      $('#navi ul li').hide();
      $('#navi ul').removeClass('open');
      $(this).find('li').slideDown();
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.open {
  display: block;
}

ul li {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navi">
  <ul title="mounting" id="1" class="39 mounting" data-color="anthrazit">
    Mounting
    <li id="0" class="261">
      <div class="label"><strong>grey</strong>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="1" class="262">
      <div class="label"><strong>black</strong>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="263">
      <div class="label"><strong>white</strong>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is behaving as such because when you click li's, the parent ul is also clicked with that, so your .click events gets fired.

Remove `open` class from the `ul element`

```
<div id="navi">
  <ul title="mounting" id="1" class="39 mounting" data-color="anthrazit">
    Mounting
    <li id="0" class="261">
      <div class="label"><strong>grey</strong>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="1" class="262">
      <div class="label"><strong>black</strong>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="263">
      <div class="label"><strong>white</strong>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now change your Javascript accordingly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navi ul:not(.open)').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("39")) {
      $('#navi ul li').hide();
      $('#navi ul').removeClass('open');
      $(this).find('li').slideDown();
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });
});

    if ($(e.target).hasClass("39")) { //`this line will tell the code that if UL is clicked then only do the rest`
```

Comment: it throws an error: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prop is not a function"

Comment: Ok, looks good. But: I have updated my code. I have more than one ul. Your suggestion is working only with one ul. Can you help ?

Comment: Updated the code snippet. keep class 39 same for all the UL's you want. And try above code

Comment: I saw your edit. I have update my script. It will work for you

Comment: I only can open one of the ul-elements. Switching between both ul is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more simple than u doing:

```js
$(".nav").click(function(event){
    $("ul li").slideToggle("slow")
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="nav">Mounting </div>
<ul title="mounting" id="0" class="39 mountin" data-color="anthrazit">
    
    <li id="0" class="261">
        <div class="label"><strong>grey</strong>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="1" class="262">
        <div class="label"><strong>black</strong>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="263">
        <div class="label"><strong>white</strong>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="nav">Mounting 2</div>
<ul title="mounting" id="3" class="39 mountin" data-color="anthrazit">
    
    <li id="4" class="261">
        <div class="label"><strong>grey</strong>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="5" class="262">
        <div class="label"><strong>black</strong>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="6" class="263">
        <div class="label"><strong>white</strong>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Comment: you did not solve OP's issue. His issue is he did not want the sliding to happen when`li` is clicked. you need to take care of that

Comment: As I have more than one UL element this will only open the li-elements inside of one ul. How can I open the li elements of both ul's ?

Comment: @Mamulasa Edited, now it works as u want, hope it helps